# MongoDB Error: Cannot use retryable writes with limit=0

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm currently working on my first node.js rest api with express, mongodb (atlas cloud) and mongoose, when i try to make a .remove request i get this error:

```
{
"error": {
    "name": "MongoError",
    "message": "Cannot use (or request) retryable writes with limit=0",
    "driver": true,
    "index": 0,
    "code": 72,
    "errmsg": "Cannot use (or request) retryable writes with limit=0"
}
```

This is my request:

```
router.delete('/:productId', (req, res, next) => {
const id = req.params.productId;
Product.remove({ _id: id })
    .exec()
    .then(result => {
        res.status(200).json(result);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        })
    }); ;
});
```

Comment: That's odd. Are you actually passing anything special on the connection string or other options on `mongoose.connect()`? I'm pretty sure Atlas clusters just all got upgraded to MongoDB 3.6 ( which is where the retryable writes is coming from ) but there really should not be anything "by default" which is turning this feature on. So if you're doing something "special", then enquiring minds would like to know.

Comment: Can you actually show the value of the variable in your question please. Also the code where you issue the the `connect()` will be useful as well. Just in case.

Comment: I see well and yes, that was the problem, the url i copied from the atlas mongoDB has already in it the retryWrites=true at the end, problem solved! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ouch! Probably should not have that in the default "suggested" URL from the console. I'd probably take that up as a support request because I see others doing the exact same thing you did.

Comment: Hi @GonzaloRodriguez , could you confirm your MongoDB Atlas deployment version ? also, whether the mongoose version that you used is either v5 and above, OR v4.11 and above ? I've just tried to reproduce this issue, and MongoDB Atlas deployment v3.4 would not show `retryWrites=true` in the URL, although v3.6 deployment would.

Comment: Sure! Im using MongoDB Atlas version 3.6.4 and Mongoose version 5.0.18

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The findOneAndRemove() function would work more accordingly since its specific to the filtering method passed in the function .findOneAndRemove(filter, options) to remove the filtered object. Still, if the remove process is interrupted by the connection the **retryRewrites=true** will attempt the execution of the function when connected.

More information [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndDelete/)

When using retryRewrites set to true tells the MongoDB to retry the same process again which in fact can help prevent failed connections to the database and operate correctly, so having it turn on is recommended.

More info [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/retryable-writes/)

If you are using Mongoose 5^ and MongoDB 3.6 your code is better written like:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb.....mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true', (err) => {
if(err){
    console.log("Could not connect to MongoDB (DATA CENTER) ");
    }else{
        console.log("DATA CENTER - Connected")
    }
});// CONNECTING TO MONGODB v. 3.6

router.delete('/:productId', (req, res, next) => {
const id = req.params.productId;
Product.findOneAndRemove({ _id: id })//updated function from .remove()
    .exec()
    .then(result => {
        res.status(200).json({
       message: "Product Removed Successfuly"
     });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        })
    }); ;
});
```

Answer (score 6):

I just changed the true to false in `retryWrites=true` and it worked. Is that a good approach? Or there is a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: That works, although complete removing the ?retryWrites=true also worked for me.

Comment: Not a good approach at all. `When using retryRewrites set to true tells the MongoDB to retry the same process again which in fact can help prevent failed connections to the database and operate correctly, so having it turn on is recommended.` See: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/retryable-writes/

Answer (score 3):

`retryWrites=true` is a good thing, a workaround for this incompatibility is to use `findOneAndRemove` instead of `remove` (looks like you're using mongoose)