# DocumentDB/MongoDB UpdateOne - Retryable writes are not supported

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, aws-documentdb

I have following bulk_write to upsert each document from my dataset to a collection.

```py
data = [] # list of dicts/documents
mongo = MongoClient('some_host')
db = mongo['some_db']
collection = db['some_collection']
operations = [UpdateOne({'_id': d['_id']}, {'$set': d}, upsert=True) for d in data]
result = collection.bulk_write(operations)
```

It runs fine running on a local MongoDB server but I am getting following error message when running on AWS DocumentDB. There's a way around which is I delete and insert each record, but want to understand why this happens and use Update instead of Delete+Insert

`pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Retryable writes are not supported, full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'code': 301, 'errmsg': 'Retryable writes are not supported', 'operationTime': Timestamp(1638883052, 1)}`

Answer (score 9):

Amazon DocumentDB does not currently support retryable writes so they need to be disabled with retryWrites=False since they are enabled by default by the driver as explained here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/functional-differences.html#functional-differences.retryable-writes

Answer (score 2):

So, Retryable writes allow MongoDB drivers to automatically retry certain write operations a single time if they encounter network errors.
However DocumentDB keeps its enabled by default and to disable you need to modify the connection string and include `&retryWrites=False`.

```
from typing import Dict
from pymongo import MongoClient


DATABASE = "SampleDatabase"

def initialize_conn() -> Dict:
    CONNECTION_STRING = f"mongodb://{username}:{password}@{host}/?ssl=true&ssl_ca_certs=global-bundle.pem&retryWrites=false"
    mongo = MongoClient(CONNECTION_STRING)[DATABASE]

    return {"MongoClient": mongo}
```

Learn More about Retriable Writes here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/core/retryable-writes/#retryable-writes

Answer (score 0):

As per this answer:

[Mongoose findOneAndUpdate throw "Retryable writes are not supported" error when working with aws Documentdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65453371/mongoose-findoneandupdate-throw-retryable-writes-are-not-supported-error-when)

`retryWrites=False`, adding this to MongoClient worked :)

Comment: retryWrites=False  Adding this to the mongo connection url as a query param worked for me as my java project is the mongo client.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to deal with this by disabling retryable writes with Rails 7.0.5 and mongoid 8.0.3 by adding `retry_writes: false` in the options stanza for my DB config in mongoid.yml